# How to not show yellow focus on form (input or textarea) just like on Facebook

Tags: javascript, css

I see that the form elements on Facebook are not highlighted when in focus.
how can I do that?

With chrome for example if I click on this textarea it becomes orange or yellow.

Answer (score 2):

```
input:focus{outline:0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply change some styles for your form elements and the browser's defaults will not take effect.

Answer (score 0):

```
.textArea:focus
{
background-color:#FFF;
}
```

Apply this class to your textareas. Or apply them to all your areas at once:

```
input:focus
    {
    background-color:#FFF;
    }
```